# Что хотят от меня Китайцы

Tags: веб-программирование, домен

Уже не раз получаю письмо от Китайского регистратора доменов по поводу моего домена.

> Dear Manager,
>
> (If you are not the person who is in charge of this, please forward this to your CEO,Thanks)
>
> This email is from China domain name registration center, which mainly deal with the domain name registration and dispute internationally in China.
>   We received an application from H-----n Ltd on March 17, 2014. They want to register " w----b " as their Internet Keyword and " w----b .cn "、" w----b .com.cn " 、" w----b .net.cn "、" w----b .org.cn " domain names etc.., they are in China domain names. But after checking it, we find " w----b " conflicts with your company. In order to deal with this matter better, so we send you email and confirm whether this company is your distributor or business partner in China or not?

Best Regards,
Jim
General Manager

(Английский я перевел) Зачем они меня спрашивают и что от меня хотят?

Comment: Как я понял, у вас зарегистрирован домен `wtruib`, однако какая-то китайская компания хочет зарегистрировать эти домены себе. И вас спрашивают, является ли эта компания вашим партнёром в Китае.

Comment: Вы имеете какое то отношение к указанной компании и указанным доменам? Возможно, у вас зарегистрирован домен wtruib.com или wtruib.org или что то подобное. Вот они и обратились. Ведь это слово может быть чей то (Вашей) торговой маркой.

Comment: То есть если я не регистрировал это слово как бренд, то они спокойно регистрируют эти домены  на .cn, .com.cn, .net.cn etc.? Если я претендую на это слово как название моей торговой марке, то этот регистратор откажет той компании? Просто месяцев 6 назад я получал подобные письма от регистраторов с попыткой зарегистрировать этот домен другими компаниями. И писма от самих компаний о том что это имя важно для них. Что они от меня хотят? какого то разрешения что ли?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что к программированию не имеет отношения. Это вопрос больше к юристам..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Это просто развод.** 
Предлагают зарегистрировать все китайские домены с твоим именем. Типо на них там очередь. Но они как добропорядочные регистраторы спрашивают тебя зарегистрировать первым.

Answer (score 5):

они перестраховываются. А вдруг у Вас сильные юристы. И засудят всех на кучу денег. Что можно сделать:

- забыть об этом.
- предложить компании выкупить у вас свой домен, соответственно у них больше не будет проблем.
- самостоятельно зарегистрировать эти домены (хотя, если у Вас нет китайского гражданства или компаний в Китае, то это может быть накладно, хотя может у меня устаревшая инфа).
- написать, что Вы подобным не интересуетесь, компанию не знаете и не хотите больше о ней слышать.